# Convert HTML strings in JSON input to XML nodes

Tags: html, json, parsing, xquery, basex

I'm trying to parse a json file with BaseX 10.7 thanks to the `json:parse` function.

My file presents some values with html characters, for example like this in "text" value:

```
   "order": 2,
   "page_id": 27,
   "text": "<p><strong>Présentation générale</strong></p>\r\n<p>L’ambon également nommé <em>pulpitium</em> (estrade) est une sorte de tribune élevée d’où sont proclamés les textes saints. Il est placé dans le chœur de l’église, généralement, du côté gauche.</p>\r\n<p>Dès la fin du IV<sup>e</sup> siècle, ce type de tribune, appelé <em>analogium</em>...<em>Bernard Berthod</em></h4>"
```

But before I even try to parse my file, when I open it in BaseX, I can see in the output window that some characters (ex : `<`) have been replaced by their encoding sign (becomes `&lt;`).

```
<order type="number">2</order><page__id type="number">27</page__id><text>&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Présentation générale&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&#xD;
&lt;p&gt;L’ambon également nommé &lt;em&gt;pulpitium&lt;/em&gt; (estrade) est une sorte de tribune élevée d’où sont proclamés les textes saints. Il est placé dans le chœur de l’église, généralement, du côté gauche.&lt;/p&gt;&#xD;..>
```

I suppose that I have to tell BaseX to accept html characters?

I tried to play with the parser options (json and html), but nothing changed...

Answer (score 0):

When you use `json:parse`, strings in the JSON structure…

```xml
{ "content": "<p>123</p>" }
```

…will be adopted as string values in the converted XML:

```xml
<json type="object">
  <content>&lt;p&gt;123&lt;/p&gt;</content>
</json>
```

The reason why the returned string representation of the XML document contains `&lt;` and `&gt;` is that the characters `<`, `>` are returned as “entity references”. Otherwise, strings with `<`/`>` and elements could not be distinguished anymore.

What (I assume) you want is that XML strings in the JSON are converted to XML:

```xml
<json type="object">
  <content><p>123</p></content>
</json>
```

This can be done by performing an update on the generated XML document: The string value of the `content` element is replaced with the parsed XML structure:

```
let $xml := json:parse('{ "content": "<p>123</p>" }')
return $xml update {
  for $text in json/content/text()
  return replace node $text with parse-xml-fragment($text)
}
```

Please note that this requires that the string is well-formed XML (which is not the case for the snippet that you presented in your question).

Comment: Thanks for you help ! I succeded to get a well formed output with this string `'{ "content": "<p style=\"text-align: right;\"><em><strong></strong></em></p>"}'`. But it seems to doesn't work when I change the key value, or example : `'{ "toto": "<p style=\"text-align: right;\"><em><strong></strong></em></p>"}'. It only gives me a result with this form : `<json type="object"><toto>&lt;p style="text-align: right;"&gt;&lt;em&gt;&lt;strong&gt;&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</toto></json>`. Would you know why ? Function's documentation doesn't talk about a special key vocabulary...

Comment: Okay, I got it, it is because you write 'json/content/text()', and i can change that. Thanks a lot again !!